# How do I align the image on my card to the left and the text to the right?

Tags: html, css, image, frontend

I'm still pretty fresh to coding so I've been trying frontend mentor challenges to improve. The product card challenge has me stumped though. I've tried doing it solo and doing it with a tutorial but I can't get my image and text to align the way they should. I need my image, inside the div "left", and my info, inside the div "right", to be side-by-side. For some reason they are stacking on top of one another no matter what I try. Clearly I'm missing something or doing something wrong but I can't find the issue. Using float was not the first thing I attempted, however it was a final attempt to find a solution that gave me less than useful results.

I've added my html and css below but essentially, when I use float  on the divs the image itself has 0 width and the card has 0 height. Either applying float to just the image instead of the div, or not using float at all, gives one div on top of the other. Adding float to the "right" div moves the "right" div off the card entirely. I'm not sure why any of these 3 things are happening, though I emphasize the focus is not to get the float function to work, it's to get these divs aligned side-by-side on the card.

\\

```
<div class="flex-container">
   
    <div class="card">
      <div class="left" style="background-image: url('image-product-desktop.jpg')"></div>
      
      <div class="right">
        
        <p>P E R F U M E</p>
        <h2><strong>Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</strong></h2>
        <p>A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge, 
           Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.</p>
   
        <div class="prices">
        <div id="sale">
          <strong>$149.99</strong>
        </div>
        <h5><s>$169.99</s></h5>
        </div>
   
        <div class="button"> 
        <button class="cart-button">
          <img src="images\icon-cart.svg">
          Add to Cart
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

\\

\\css

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    border-radius: 18px;
    margin: 0 1em;
    width: 70%;
}

.flex-container {
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.left{
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    background-position: left;
    background-size: cover;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.right{
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 20px;
    padding: 35px 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

\\

Prior to trying float to fix the issue, I tried several things. Sometimes the image would be on the card but above the info. Sometimes it would align above the card and the info. I've tried putting both div's in flex containers, added the image in the css instead of the html, added the image directly as an element instead of as a background image. Nothing I'm doing seems to give me the outcome I'm looking for. I've included a screenshot of the final product from the frontend mentor challenge for those who may not know what I'm going for.[frontend mentor product card desktop design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYod5.jpg)

Comment: kindly provide your code in **text** not in images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.